# Trouble unit testing Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to unit test a basic Angular directive using Jasmine.

Essentially all the directive does is check that two password inputs are equal and sets the

the directive looks like this:

```
angular.module('jhApp')
.directive('jhEquals', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: linker
    };

    function linker(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) {
            return false;
        }

        //watch own value and re-validate
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
            validate();
        });

        //observe other value and re-validate on change
        attrs.$observe('jhEquals', function() {
            validate();
        });

        var validate = function() {
            var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
            var val2 = attrs.jhEquals;

            //set validity
            if(val1 && val2) {
                ngModel.$setValidity('jhEquals', !val1 || !val2 || val1 === val2);
            }
        };
    }

});
```

and the spec looks like this:

```
var scope,
    dirElement;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('jhApp');
        module('templates');

        inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
            scope = $rootScope;
            scope.user = {};

            dirElement = angular.element('<input id="password" type="password" name="password" ng-model="user.password" jh-equals="{{user.passwordconfirm}}"><input id="newpasswordconfirm" type="password" name="newpasswordconfirm" ng-model="user.passwordconfirm" jh-equals="{{user.password}}>');

            $compile(dirElement)(scope);
        });

        scope.$digest();
    });


it('should check if values are equal', function() {
    var passwordInput = dirElement.find('#password');
    var confirmPasswordInput = dirElement.find('#newpasswordconfirm');

    angular.element(passwordInput).val('testpassword').trigger('input');
    angular.element(confirmPasswordInput).val('nottestpassword').trigger('input');
    scope.$digest();

    //expect this to be invalid

});
```

passwordInput &  confirmPasswordInput - are showing an empty objects when I console.log it out and if I check the values of val1 and val2 in validate() in the directive it is always undefined.

So I guess the issue here is that I cannot figure out how to select the inputs to add the content to.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but there are still some smalls issues happening.

First you need to place the directive inside a form in order to test the validicity. Also check that the last jh-equals value binding it miss a " .

Second the jqlite find function it only works with elements selectors. So is not possible to select an element like dirElement.find('#testpassword') but yes as dirElement.find('input'). The reason why they have take off this functionality from the jqlite is to make it much more light. Instead you can make a dirElement.find('input') and select the desired input by index. It may seems a grunt task but anyway most of the times that you need to select an element in jqlite it would be in a small set inside the dom tree, like in a test enviroment or in the inner doom from some directive.

Finally the jqlite trigger is called as triggerHandler not a trigger.

The final picture should be something like this:

```
var scope, dirElement;

beforeEach(function() {
  module('jhApp');
  module('templates');

  inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    scope.user = {};

    dirElement = $compile([
      '<form name="form">',
      '<input id="password" type="password" name="password"',
      ' ng-model="user.password" jh-equals="{{user.passwordconfirm}}" />',
      '<input id="newpasswordconfirm" type="password"',
      ' name="newpasswordconfirm" ng-model="user.passwordconfirm"',
      ' jh-equals="{{user.password}}" />',
      '</form>',
    ].join(''))(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  });

});

it('invalid  if the values are not equal', function() {
  var passwordInput = dirElement.find('input');
  var confirmPasswordInput = dirElement.find('input')[1];

  angular.element(passwordInput)
        .val('testpassword')
        .triggerHandler('input');
  angular.element(confirmPasswordInput)
        .val('nottestpassword')
        .triggerHandler('input');

  expect(scope.form.password.$invalid).toBe(true);
  expect(scope.form.password.$valid).toBe(false);
  expect(scope.form.password.$dirty).toBe(true);
  expect(scope.form.newpasswordconfirm.$invalid).toBe(true);
  expect(scope.form.newpasswordconfirm.$valid).toBe(false);
  expect(scope.form.newpasswordconfirm.$dirty).toBe(true);
});

it('valid  if the values are equal', function() {
  var passwordInput = dirElement.find('input');
  var confirmPasswordInput = dirElement.find('input')[1];

  angular.element(passwordInput)
        .val('testpassword')
        .triggerHandler('input');
  angular.element(confirmPasswordInput)
        .val('testpassword')
        .triggerHandler('input');

  expect(scope.form.password.$invalid).toBe(false);
  expect(scope.form.password.$valid).toBe(true);
  expect(scope.form.password.$dirty).toBe(true);
  expect(scope.form.newpasswordconfirm.$invalid).toBe(false);
  expect(scope.form.newpasswordconfirm.$valid).toBe(true);
  expect(scope.form.newpasswordconfirm.$dirty).toBe(true);

});
```